# Performance testing on big data

Tags: performance-testing, robotframework, bigdata

I'm new in performance testing and I have to test the performances of some processes on big data (basically Spark streaming/batch).

I'd like to know which are the best tools (easy to use, performant, robust, ...) to do it and, if possible, if they can be integrated in Robot Framework (e.g. I already saw in another question that there is a plugin for Jmeter but personally the tool seems too much web oriented).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use any python load generating library and induce heavy traffic for your application. Measurements can be triggered directly at the webserver level using a monitoring tool. I have used Locust in the past to test spark/hdfs. Locust is like jmeter, but python-based. [Link](http://locust.io/) The advantage to this approach is that mitigation scripts can be directly designed based on usage patterns right at the server level and tested simultaneously.

Edit: To your question of whether they can be integrated in Robotframework, yes there can be some loose coupling, but I wouldn't recommend that because robotframework, by nature, is a functional/regression test framework